# Comment Spammed vs Trashed

Tags: spam, trash

What's the difference between marking a comment as spam and trashing it?

Comment: Well, for one thing, if you have Akismet running, marking a comment as spam will tell Akismet and it'll use that comment to learn what to mark as spam automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vanilla WordPress the only difference is that trashed comments [get deleted automatically after (customizable) time span](http://codex.wordpress.org/Trash_status#Default_Days_before_Permanently_Deleted).

Adding plugins to the picture - it might make difference to what/how specific plugin learns from incoming spam.